# How to count the difference between a random int array elements values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm a beginner and need help with following:-)There is a random int array, the values(0-10) are showing the level of terrain, I need to count first how much water can be stored on this ground structure. For example int[] randomTerrain = {8, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 6, 9}; the water strorage capacity of this groundstructure is 0+4+0+6+2+5+6+7+2+0=32. I have two questions, first how to count it from a random int array?
Second is a bit different as I need to print out and visualize it in a 2D string array [10][10] where string ground = "*"; string water = "-"; and the air is empty space.
Thanks in advance for Your help! below You can se what I've done, but it is not wotrking as expected.
GhostCats resolution is perfect but as we did not learn still about stream methods it would be apreciate if somebody could help with a bit different resolution using only simple methods.
package Rezervoir;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Rezervoir {

```
private static final int TERRAIN_HEIGHT = 10;
private static final int TERRAIN_WIDTH = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] randomTerrain = createRandomTerrain();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomTerrain));
                    
    int waterStorageCapacity = countWaterCapacity(randomTerrain);       
    System.out.println(waterStorageCapacity);   
    System.out.println();
    String[][] terrain = {
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}
    };

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    for (column = 0 ; column < terrain[0].length ; column++) {

        for (row = 0 ; row < terrain.length ; row++) {

            if ((terrain.length -1) -row <= randomTerrain[column]) {

                terrain[column][row] = "*";
            }
            System.out.print(terrain[terrain.length-1-row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
private static int countWaterCapacity(int[] randomTerrain) {
    int capacitySum = 0;
    int firstTop = 0;   
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < randomTerrain.length -1 ; i++) {           
        
        if (randomTerrain[i] >= randomTerrain[i+1]) {
            firstTop = randomTerrain[i];            
        }               
            else if (randomTerrain[i+1] >= randomTerrain[i])    {
                firstTop = randomTerrain[i+1];                  
            }               
        int capacity = 0;
        capacity = firstTop - randomTerrain[i];
        capacitySum += capacity;            
    }
    return capacitySum;
}
private static int[] createRandomTerrain() {
    int[] randomTerrain = new int[TERRAIN_WIDTH];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < randomTerrain.length ; i ++) {
        randomTerrain[i] = (int) (Math.random() * TERRAIN_HEIGHT + 1);

    }
    return randomTerrain;       
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand your question. `For example int[] randomTerrain = {8, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 6, 9}; the water strorage capacity of this groundstructure is 0+4+0+6+2+5+6+7+2+0=32` ... how does the first array relate to that number 32? It s not clear how you compute that number!!! That is the key thing here: before you start thinking about writing code to solve a problem ... enable yourself to *explain* the problem. To you, and the people you are asking to help.

Comment: So sorry if I was not clear, int array is ground structure first element is 8 second is 4 and third is again 8 in this case if You imagine as 8 is 8 meter wall and between two 8m walls on a 4meter platform can be stored 4 units of water, in case if the first value is 10 and decreasing till the end of array than can not store any water.

Comment: Thank You, will keep in mind Your suggestion, code is great

Comment: Dear GhostCat, Your code is perfect, but we still not learned about the stream methods I cant use it to prepare my homework. Could You please help me to write it with simple methods? If You check my triggers above You can see what I mean. I started of course study the methods used by you in your code and tried to simplify it to write it my way but couldn't, so it has to be done by more simple methods. Thanks in adavance for Your help!

Answer (score 0):

the code's meaning is basically explained in the comments. this may solve your problem but maybe it's not the most efficient way. You can explore more ways by yourself.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] terrain = { 8, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 6, 9 };
        int[] capacity = countCapacity(terrain);
        int sum = Arrays.stream(capacity).sum();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(capacity));
        System.out.println(sum);
        printGraph(terrain,capacity);
    }

    public static void printGraph(int[] terrain, int[] capacity) {
        // find the max height, and it will be the row numbers of console output.
        int maxHeight = Arrays.stream(terrain).max().orElse(0);
        for (int j = maxHeight; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < terrain.length; i++) {
                // if terrain height is lower than current printing height.
                if (terrain[i] < j){
                    // and terrain's capacity + height is lower, just print space
                    if (capacity[i] + terrain[i] < j){
                        System.out.print("   ");
                    // otherwise, print water
                    }else {
                        System.out.print(" - ");
                    }
                // if terrain height is higher than current printing height. print terrain
                }else {
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                }
            }
            // make a new row.
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[] countCapacity(int[] terrain) {
        List<Integer> terranList = Arrays.stream(terrain).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        int[] capacity = new int[terrain.length];
        // the first and last terrain's capacity must be 0. just set it first.
        capacity[0] = 0;
        capacity[capacity.length - 1] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < terrain.length - 1; i++) {
            // if there's no terrain higher than current terrain at left. then it can not hold water.
            // so it's capacity is 0, and skip to next terrain.
            int currentHeight = terrain[i];
            int leftHighest = Collections.max(terranList.subList(0, i));
            if (leftHighest <= currentHeight) {
                capacity[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            // if there's no higher terrain in the right. the same as above.
            int rightHighest = Collections.max(terranList.subList(i + 1, terranList.size()));
            if (rightHighest <= currentHeight) {
                capacity[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            // if there are higher terrain int both direction. this terrain can hold water.
            // and its capacity is the lower one minus this terrain's height.
            capacity[i] = Math.min(leftHighest, rightHighest) - currentHeight;
        }
        return capacity;
    }
}
```

the output may like:

```
[0, 4, 0, 6, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2, 0]
32
                            * 
 *  -  *  -  -  -  -  -  -  * 
 *  -  *  -  -  -  -  -  -  * 
 *  -  *  -  *  -  -  -  *  * 
 *  -  *  -  *  -  -  -  *  * 
 *  *  *  -  *  -  -  -  *  * 
 *  *  *  -  *  *  -  -  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  -  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
```